# foreach loop from multiple arrays c#

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach

This should be a simple question. All I want to know is if there is a better way of coding this. I want to do a foreach loop for every array, without having to redeclare the foreach loop. Is there a way c# projects this? I was thinking of putting this in a Collection...?

Please, critique my code.

```
        foreach (TextBox tb in vert)
        {
            if (tb.Text == box.Text)                
                conflicts.Add(tb);                
        }
        foreach (TextBox tb in hort)
        {
            if (tb.Text == box.Text)                
                conflicts.Add(tb);                
        }
        foreach (TextBox tb in cube)
        {
            if (tb.Text == box.Text)
                conflicts.Add(tb);                
        }
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using?

Comment: Can a single textbox be in two of the lists?

Comment: Yes, in short, each array is a textbox[] of cube, hort, and vert Textboxes of a sudoku prog. So for structural purposes, I'd like to have each array independent of others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
conflicts.AddRange(
    vert.Concat(hort).Concat(cube)
        .Where(tb => tb.Text == box.Text)
);
```

I'm assuming that `conflicts` is a `List<TextBox>`, which has an `AddRange` method.  If it isn't, you'll need to call `Add` in a (single) loop.
If you're creating `conflicts`, (or if it starts empty), you can call `.ToList()` instead.

Comment: I changed my conflicts var from TextBox[] to List<TextBox>. works great! Thanks to all the responses!

Comment: You can also write `conflicts = (...).ToArray()`.

Comment: because there is once instance of the same textbox in each array, I simply add the where clause (... && tb.Name != box.Name) –

Comment: @Mike: ` && tb != box`.  You don't need to compare the `Name` strings.

Answer (score 3):

Another .net 3.5 approach:-

```
conflicts.AddRange(from textBox in vert.Concat(hort).Concat(cube)
                   where textBox.Text == box.Text
                   select textBox);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use LINQ for whatever reason (and I highly suggest you do) you could make your array searching a single method. For example:

```
public void FindConflicts(IEnumerable<TextBox> tbList, IList<TextBox> conflicts, string test)
{
   foreach(TextBox tb in tbList)
   {
      if(tb.Text == test)
      {
          conflicts.Add(tb);
      }
   }
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
FindConflicts(vert, conflicts, box.Text);
FindConflicts(hort, conflicts, box.Text);
FindConflicts(cube, conflicts, box.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are of course many ways to write this, but you could also do

```
  foreach (var direction in new[] { vert, hort, cube })
    foreach (TextBox tb in direction)
      if (tb.Text == box.Text)
        conflicts.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var unionResult = vert.Concat(hort).Concat(cube)

foreach(TextBox tb in unionResult)
    if(tb.Text == box.Text)
        conflicts.Add(tb);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to [use Enumerable.Concat to glue them together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx) if you're using .Net 3.5 or higher.

```
foreach (TextBox tb in vert.Concat(hort).Concat(cube))
```

Comment: `Union` will remove duplicates

Comment: I do not want to remove dups, as each array is a collection of 9 textboxes. If Union eliminates dups, is there a natural join function?

Comment: @Slaks - thanks.  I knew that (and included a link to the documentation on Enumerable.Concat), but my fingers didn't cooperate with my brain when I typed out the code example.  I edited it to use the Concat method instead of Union.

Answer (score -1):

If you try to create Sudoku game(mentioned in comments) first read about Permutation group and Combinatorics.
This will help you to choose more efficient Application Model w/o using foreach on text boxes. Using lazy computation resolve the problem with object reduction but not improve your logics man.

Comment: I appreciate the reference, but this is entirely for learning purposes.